# Qual o tempo de vida de um Instancia de classe e uma "Instancia de Módulo"?

Tags: python

Uma instancia de objeto existe até que seu pai seja destruído, ou seja:

```
class AnyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.any_date = datetime.date.today()
```

(`any_date`)Existirá até o momento que seu "objeto pai" (instancia de `AnyClass`) seja pego e destruído pelo coletor de lixo.

E qual seria o tempo de vida de objetos de classe e "objetos de modulo"?

Objeto de classe:

```
class AnyClass:
    any_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Qual o tempo de vida de `any_time`?

Objeto de modulo:

```
#file test.py

ANY_DATE = datetime.date.today()

class AnyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.any_date = datetime.date.today()
```

Qual o tempo de vida de `ANY_DATE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Classes e módulos existem durante toda a vida do processo, desde o momento em que o módulo é importado pela primeira vez (no caso de classes, as classes existentes dentro dos módulos). Os atributos dessas classes e módulos também acompanham a vida dos seus "pais". Só deixam de existir se forem apagados explicitamente pelo comando `del`.

**resposta completa**

Uma das coisas legais em Python é que a linguagem funciona com um conjunto pequeno de regras e há pouquíssimas exceções ou casos especiais.

Então, você já deve ter ouvido falar que "tudo em Python é um objeto". o "tudo" é "tudo" - inclusive classes e módulos.

E por padrão, objetos em Python tem, internamente, uma contagem de referências: isso é - cada referência, seja um nome de variável, seja como conteúdo de uma estrutura de dados como uma lista, dicionário ou conjunto há um objeto aumenta essa contagem de referência em "1". Quando a última referência a um objeto é destruída e a contagem de referências do objeto chega a zero, seu método `__del__`  é chamado e, em seguida,  o objeto é descartado e sua memória é liberada (essa destruição não depende de código no método `__del__` - ela é feita pelo runtime da linguagem - mesmo que o  `__del__` não chame o método correspondente nas super-classes).

Então, é só acertar a terminologia e fica fácil responder a sua pergunta: 
O que você está chamando de "instância de objeto" são na verdade "atributos de instância" (os atributos criados com `self. ...` dentro de métodos do objeto). O que você chama de "objetos de classe" -  atribuições de nome feitas no corpo de um comando `class` - são "atributos de classe". O que você chama de "objeto de módulo" pode ter esse nome, ou podemos simplesmente chamar de "variáveis no nível do módulo" ou "variáveis globais" (são chamadas "globais", mas na verdade sempre são no nível do módulo).

E, cada um dos objetos que você está em dúvida, assim como todos os demais objetos em Python, existe até o ponto em que nenhuma outra referência a ele exista.
No caso de atributos de instância, se a instância a qual eles pertencem é destruída, os atributos são destruídos junto (a não ser que exista alguma variável externa apontando para o mesmo objeto):

```
>>> class TesteApaga:
...    count = 0
...    def __init__(self):
...         self.count = self.__class__.count
...         self.__class__.count += 1
...    def __del__(self):
...         print(f"Instância {self.count} apagada!")
... 
>>> a = TesteApaga()
>>> del a
Instância 0 apagada!
>>> class B:
...   def __init__(self):
...      self.a = TesteApaga()
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> del b
Instância 1 apagada!
```

Mas não:

```
>>> b = B()
Instância 6 apagada!
>>> c = b.a
>>> del b
>>> # há uma referência ainda dentro da variável 'c'
... 
>>> del c
Instância 2 apagada!
```

Para atributos de classe, vale o mesmo - quando a própria classe em que o atributo é declarado é apagada, seus atributos são apagados.

O que acontece aí é que as classes em si são anotadas em alguns registros internos - pelo menos em `object.__subclasses__`, por exemplo, então nem sempre quando damos o comando  `del` para apagar uma classe, a contagem de referência da classe em si chega a zero - nesse caso, sim, entra em ação  o "garbage colector" - em algum ponto, depois de um `del` na própria classe ele vai "perceber" que a classe não tem mais referências e apagar a propria classe internamente. Nesse ponto, seus atributos também são destruídos.

No modo interativo, ao declarar:

```
>>> class C:
...   c = TesteApaga()
... 
>>> del C
```

Não foi impresso "instancia 2 apagada" imediamente - apenas algumas linhas depois quando fui usar o recurso de "autocompletar" do shell.

Claro que em vez de depender da classe ser apagada, se você quiser liberar recursos que estão no objeto em questão, sempre pode usar o `del` explicitamente:

```
>>> class D:
...   d = TesteApaga()
... 
>>> d = D()
>>> 
>>> del D.d
Instância 3 apagada!
```

Nesse caso, ao contrário de quando apagamos diretamente o `D`, não há necessidade de aguardar o garbage colector.

Para módulos a mesma coisa - 
Uma variável (ou declaraçao de função, ou declaração de classe, ou nome importado) num módulo fica com uma referência no dicionário interno daquele módulo (o atributo `.__dict__` do próprio módulo).

Basta apagar o atributo do módulo diretamente e aquela referência deixa de existir.

Agora, o que nunca vai bastar é apagar o módulo apenas do namespace local - quando um módulo é importado em Python, além dos nomes no lugar onde foi feito o `import`, há uma referência ao módulo que fica em `sys.modules` - que é um dicionário onde as chaves são os nomes dos módulos, e os valores são os objetos "módulo" eles mesmos. Ao se apagar um módulo tanto do namespace local quando de `sys.modules`, sim, se o módulo não foi importado em nenhum outro ponto no mesmo processo, suas referências chegam a 0, e os seus atributos são destruídos.

Neste exemplo, eu crio um arquivo ".py" vazio, que é importado como um módulo,
crio um objeto lá dentro - veja como ele é apagado apenas quando o excluo do sys.modules:

```
>>> open("modulo_teste.py", "wt")
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='modulo_teste.py' mode='wt' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> import modulo_teste
>>> modulo_teste.e = TesteApaga()
>>> 
>>> del modulo_teste
>>> del sys.modules["modulo_teste"]
Instância 4 apagada!
>>>
```

Ou, claro, se for usado o `del` diretamente na variável que aponta pra ele:

```
>>> import modulo_teste
>>> modulo_teste.f = TesteApaga()
>>> 
>>> del modulo_teste.f
Instância 5 apagada!
>>>
```

**Voltando à sua pergunta sobre o "tempo de vida"**: num programa em Python "normal", módulos e classes declaradas como código dentro dos módulos tipicamente não são apagados nunca - esses objetos existem desde que o módulo é importado e executado, e persistem até o final do programa.

Apenas a remoção explícita desses objetos com o comando `del` faz com que sejam destruídos antes.

**E por fim**, claro que se o programa fizer uso de técnicas de multi-processamento em processos externos como "subprocess", "concurrent.futures" ou "celery",que criam processos de trabalho (worker processes),  quando esses processos-filho forem encerrados os objetos respectivos também são destruídos - acrescento essa informação caso algum dos atributos aponte para um arquivo aberto, ou socket em porta - recursos do sistema operacional que só podem ser usados por um processo por vez.

Em aplicações Python de backend web, em produção, tipicamente o número de processos/threads de uma aplicação não está sob controle do desenvolvedor - o servidor WSGI é que controla isso. Nessas, em cada *processo*  as classes e módulos são criados de forma independente. (por exemplo, se sua app estiver sendo servida em 5 processos com 4 threads em cada, Python vai executar o código que cria sua classe 5 vezes - e elas serão visíveis em todas as 20 threads que existem no total).

Comment: Olá João! Desculpe retomar a pergunta após marcá-la como respondida, é que uma nova dúvida surgiu.
Nesse caso instancias de classe começam a existir a partir do momento que o programa executa e são destruídas a partir do momento que a classe também é destruída. Se a classe não for destruída manualmente ou seja, por meio do comando `del` ela existirá do começo até o fim da aplicação, bem como suas respectivas instancias, ou seja, com um comportamento igual a variáveis globais, onde elas existes enquanto o modulo existir que pode ser "sempre". É isso?
Isso pode ocasionar **memory leak**?

Comment: Isso - uma classe ou módulo é criada, e existe pra sempre - e os atributos declarados na classe existem enquanto o programa estiver em execução a não ser que a própria declaração da classe seja apagada explicitamente por um `del`. (e, no caso de módulos, o `del` tem que ser também no `sys.modules["modulo"]`) (de novo insisto na terminologia: "atributo da classe" não "instância" - "instância da classe" é o termo para um objeto criado com aquela classe, que normalmente tem uma vida mais curta)